# Bash replacing text with sed - not recognized string

Tags: bash, vagrant-provision

I'm writing a bash script to provision my server using vagrant.
my provision script is an external bash script.

Currently i'm trying to set the banner inside my ssh_config file but it doesn't seem to work.

I was looking on the internet on how to replace a string within a file:
the default in ssh_config is '#Banner none' which needs 'Banner /etc/issue.net'.

My problem is that I always get a permission denied on /etc/issue.net, but i'm thinking that it sees the string as a file to access rather than the string to replace.

my command

```
text_to_find="#Banner none"
text_to_replace= '"Banner /etc/issue.net"'
sed -i 's/$text_to_find/$text_to_replace/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

First I tried without the single quotes, I tried to escape the string but none of the things I tried was helpfull.

Comment: cut-n-paste your code, along with appropriate shebang, into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and make the recommended changes; of particular interest ... when assigning a value to a variable there is no space on either side of the `=`, and variables are not expanded when enclosed in single quotes; that should get you closer ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second assignment is not an assignment; with a space after the `=`, it tries to run a command named `"Banner /etc/issue.net"`, which probably doesn't exist, with the variable set to the empty string inside that command's environment.

Also, your quotes in the `sed` command are wrong, so once you do get the assignment right, you'll be asking `sed` to look for the literal text `$text_to_find` and replace it with `$text_to_replace`, instead of the strings you stored in those variables.

Finally, you can't use `/` as the delimiter for the sed `s` command if there are `/`s inside the search or replacement text.  Once you fix the assignment and quotes and get the actual text you want into the sed, what you'll wind up with is this:

```
sed -i "s/$text_to_find/$text_to_replace/g"
```

which expands into this:

```
sed -i 's/#Banner none/"#Banner /etc/issue.net"/g'
```

With five `/`s in it. How is `sed` supposed to know which ones separate the arguments to `s`, and which ones are meant to be part of those arguments?  Fortunately you don't have to use `/` as the delimiter; you can pick any character. For example:

```
sed -i "s|$text_to_find|$text_to_replace|g"
```

You could alternatively use some fancy expansion shenanigans to insert a backslash in front of all the slashes:

```
sed -i "s/${text_to_find//\//\\\/}/${text_to_replace//\//\\\/}/g"
```

but who wants leaning toothpicks all over their shell script?

Also, your assignment to `text_to_replace` includes literal quotation marks which will wind up in the file; make sure that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, i'm not a bashscripter so I tought it was something simple, however I was surprised by the delimiter cause I have been looking on the command on 4 different sites which all used forward slashes for arguments and the string to replace. anyway it is working now

Comment: Because `/` is used to indicate patterns to search for (e.g. `/foo/` to match all lines containing "foo"), it is the default delimiter for search/replace, too. But in the search/replace case you can use a different character if you want, and indeed must if you have unescaped slashes in the pattern or replacement.